# LMAX Disruptor Timeout for the EventHandler onEvent

Tags: disruptor-pattern, lmax

I have a ring buffer and an event handler. This is used as an inbound buffer of a messaging server.

Inside my even handler, it does some AMQP service invocations and some times due to that call waits without a timeout(bug in the underline protocol library which calls AMQP services). And with 2000tps, this lead my 4096 size ring buffer to FULL in a flash. Because seems the onEvent caller thread not returning from that method and waiting infinitely inside onEvent() due to aforesaid fact.

At the moment creating a timeout for that invocation is not a possibility.

Question is::

When disruptor engine calls onEvent(), can we set a timeout on Buffer creation level or some other level, where it will have a timeout on the onEvent() method call.

I am using disruptor 3.3.2 with BlockingWaitStrategy.

Answer (score 0):

The disruptor doesn't support timeouts on event handlers. However I can think of a few possible ways around this.

The simplest change would be wrap your problematic AMQP call in a [future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) on which you call `Future#get(timeout, TimeUnit)`.

There are other options around submitting the long running task to a separate disruptor to process or writing the future into another field in the event and having a second eventHandler process that.